# Is there any way to condense my code so it does not take up so many lines?

Tags: python

I'm writing my program in python and have it working properly, but it's over 500 lines of code. I think there is a way I can condense my code, but I'm not sure how I should do it

Here's an example of some of my code:

```
def click():
    if clicked1.get() == "app1":
        os.startfile(r"C:\Users\red\Desktop\app1")
        i = 0
        while i < 20:
            try:
                app.connect(title_re=".*app1")
                break
            except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
                time.sleep(1)
                i += 1
        app1 = app.top_window()
        app1.move_window(x1, y1)
        time.sleep(.5)
        app1.maximize()
    if clicked1.get() == "app2":
        os.startfile(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\app2")
        i = 0
        while i < 20:
            try:
                app.connect(title_re=".*app2")
                break
            except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
                time.sleep(1)
                i += 1
        app1 = app.top_window()
        app1.move_window(x1, y1)
        time.sleep(.5)
        app1.maximize()
```

I basically have about 20 of those if statements for each different
application and for each different clicked (1-4). Is there any way I can shrink my code so it doesn't take up so many lines? Perhaps using variables?

Comment: What's the purpose of the code? There is no description and the code is hardly self-documenting. Are you focused on reducing the amount of lines of code or would shorter (but more) functions be welcome too? One doesn't discount the other, but just making code short for the sake of shortness rarely helps anyone in the long run.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can. You can write something like this:

```py
app_str = clicked1.get()
if app_str in app_path_dict:
    os.startfile(app_path_dict[app_str])
    i = 0
    while i < 20:
        try:
            app.connect(title_re=".*" + app_str)
            break
        except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
            time.sleep(1)
            i += 1
    app1 = app.top_window()
    app1.move_window(x1, y1)
    time.sleep(.5)
    app1.maximize()
```

It looks like the only things being changed are those two strings, so that’s the only thing you need to change in the if block. And you can check if clicked1.get() is valid using the dict of apps and their paths.

*I completely missed that the paths are different, sorry about that. You can use a dict like Willi Flemming showed.

Answer (score 3):

When refactoring code that is not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) then try to identify the parts that actually do change and put those parts into some kind of data structure like a list or dictionary. Then wrap everything into a function.

```
apps = {'app1': r"C:\Users\red\Desktop\app1",
        'app2': r"C:\Program Files (x86)\app2",
        ...
       }
       
selected_app = clicked1.get()

def click():
    os.startfile(apps.get(selected_app))
    i = 0
    while i < 20:
        try:
            app.connect(title_re=".*" + selected_app)
            break
        except pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:
            time.sleep(1)
            i += 1
    app1 = app.top_window()
    app1.move_window(x1, y1)
    time.sleep(.5)
    app1.maximize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already perfect.
You could even remove two more lines by replacing the while loop with a for loop, in a more pythonic way:

Current:

```
i = 0
while i < 20:
    do something
    i += 1
```

Change:

```
for i in range(20):
    do something
```